# Is there a way to ask the user for new input while he/she types a wrong one?

Tags: c

I'm trying to ask the user for new input every time he/she types in a wrong one:

```
int year;
char temp;
do{
    printf("Please enter the year: ");
}while(scanf("%d%c",&year,&temp)!=2 || temp != '\n');
```

I tried to do this, but when I enter a wrong input (non integer), the console window starts spinning like mad and it doesn't stops.

Comment: "while" means "during the same time". With scanf you cannot do anything, while the user is typing. you have to wait until he has finished typing.

Comment: Maybe duplicate of [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53056369/c-infinite-loop-when-char-input-instead-of-int](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53056369/c-infinite-loop-when-char-input-instead-of-int).

Comment: @Holger I wonder whether some confusion arises from the fact that the C keyword `while` clearly *does not* mean "at the same time" --  I actually was confused because I thought your sentence refers to the keyword!  ;-). C's keyword `while` would be better named "and_do_again_if" or so. (To Thomson & Ritchie's defense it should be said that concurrency was not an issue in the 1970s.)

Comment: I was refering the while in the title of the question. "Asking while typing" means simultaneously.
That is not so strange, google search does a lot of things, while typing.
The keyword rather means "as long as", that is also a proper use of while,
cause "condition is true" and "do the action" happens simultanously (in human 
language sense, not in IT-sense.).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you need input from a user, *force* the user to give you want you need. Structure your read to gracefully handle whatever the user attempts to input (even a cat stepping on the keyboard). You also need to handle a manually generated `EOF` that the user can generate to cancel input by pressing <kbd>Ctrl+d</kbd> (or <kbd>Ctrl+z</kbd> on windows).

You are best served by reading a line-at-a-time with a *line-oriented* input function such as `fgets()` or POSIX `getline()` (note: all *line-oriented* function read and include the trailing `'\n'` in the buffer they fill ensuring a complete line of input is consumed). Then you can parse any values you need from the line read. Avoid using *formatted-input* functions line `scanf/fscanf` which are full of pitfalls for the new programmer because what is left in the input stream depends on the *format-specifier* used and whether a *matching* or *input* failure occurs.

The approach is simple. Loop continually prompting for input. **Check the return** of your input function. Handle the `EOF` case, then ***validate your conversion***, if any, and finally check that any value input meets the criteria you set for the input.

A simple example reading `year` would be:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAXC 1024   /* if you need a constant, #define one (or more) */

int main (void) {

    char buf[MAXC];     /* buffer to hold line (don't skimp on size) */
    int year;           /* integer to hold year */

    for (;;) {  /* loop continually to force user to provide needed input */
        fputs ("\nenter year (0-2050): ", stdout);  /* prompt */
        fflush (stdout);                            /* force display */
        if (!fgets (buf, MAXC, stdin)) {    /* read entire line of input */
            fputs ("(user canceled input)\n", stdout);
            return 0;
        }
        if (sscanf (buf, "%d", &year) != 1) {   /* validate conversion */
            fputs ("error: invalid integer input.\n", stderr);
        }
        else if (year < 0 || year > 2050) {     /* validate in range */
            fputs ("error: year entered is out of range '0-2050'.\n", stderr);
        }
        else
            break;  /* valid input received */
    }

    printf ("\nyear: %d\n", year);
}
```

Note above, you continually prompt the user for input until you force the user to enter what you need. You also allow them to cancel input at any time by gracefully handling the `EOF` condition.

With any input function your write -- go try and break it. Enter a bunch of invalid input, try and find any corner cases you have overlooked. If you can't break it, then you are far better off than the guy who writes his code, and considers it good without a thorough test.

**Example Use/Output**

Run your code and try and make the input routine fail:

```
$ ./bin/readintyear

enter year (0-2050): What do I get if I do?
error: invalid integer input.

enter year (0-2050): Banannas!
error: invalid integer input.

enter year (0-2050): 2055
error: year entered is out of range '0-2050'.

enter year (0-2050): 2019

year: 2019
```

When you are satisfied you will get what you require from the user every time, you have a good routine. Look things over and let me know if you have further questions.

Comment: If for some reason you still want to use `scanf`, it can be used, but must be used correctly. See, e.g. this answer [C: scanf did not stop in infinite while loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53474700/c-scanf-did-not-stop-in-infinite-while-loop/53474902?r=SearchResults&s=5|40.1570#53474902)