# Standard Deviation Formula

Tags: c++, math, computer-science, cmath

I have this assignment in which i will show the prompt for it:

Write a program that reads in a set of test score data from the user. (Test
scores should be entered in decimal form to represent the percentage grade). Once the user has
finished entering the test scores (entering -1 will signal the end of input), print out the number of
tests entered, the average of the tests, and the standard deviation. Use the following formula
(Welford’s method) to calculate the standard deviation:
[(Standard Deviaton Formula)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O1T2j.png)

You can compute this quantity by keeping track of the count (number of tests), the sum, and the sum
of squares as you process the input values.
Note: Although there are other ways to calculate the standard deviation, please use this method. This
method is used since it only requires one pass of the data. Do not use arrays or vectors.

Now the code below is what I have so far. In the terminal, I'm getting wrong numbers for the average and Std. Deviation outputs [(Terminal Output)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/seu1A.png). Is there anything wrong with my math? Any help is appreciated.

```
 #include <iostream>
    #include <cmath>
    using namespace std;
    int main()

    double sum = 0;
    double sumSq = 0;
    double grade = 0;
    int numtests = 0;

    cout << "Enter the test scores. Once finished, enter -1 to end input.\n";
    cin >> grade;

    while(grade != -1)
    {
            cin >>grade;
            sum = sum + grade;
            sumSq = sumSq + pow(grade,2);
            numtests++;
    }

    double average =(sum/numtests);
    double std = (sumSq - numtests*pow(average,2)/(numtests - 1));

    cout << "The number of scores: "<<numtests<<"\n";
    cout << "Average: "<<average<<"\n";
    cout << "Std. Deviation: "<<std<<"\n";




    return 0;
```

}

Comment: `bool cin = true` It's a very bad idea to name a local variable as `cin` which hides the `std::cin`. Anyway, where in your code do you read `grade` after the first time? That is, where in the loop? You can't expect `grade` to change values if you never read anything into it again.

Comment: `pow(2,grade)` is 2 raised to `grade` power, not `grade` squared.

Comment: @kaylum I am new to C++ and currently in my first year of my major. Could you explain to me in what you mean by read? Also i updated my code where I deleted the Boolean.

Comment: The simple way to look at it is after `cin >> grade;`,  `grade` contains only a single integer value. If that values isn't `-1` -- *"where in the heck does grade change?"* so it will be seen by `while(grade != -1)` as something other than the first grade entered?

Comment: You may also benefit from [cin input (input is an int) when I input a letter, instead of printing back incorrect once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50402749/cin-input-input-is-an-int-when-i-input-a-letter-instead-of-printing-back-inco/50403158#50403158) and for C [Is there a way to ask the user for new input while he/she types a wrong one?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58820397/is-there-a-way-to-ask-the-user-for-new-input-while-he-she-types-a-wrong-one/58821104#58821104)

Answer (score 3):

I find a good way to debug a program is often to pretend that I am the computer, and try stepping through the program one line at a time to see what I do.

If I follow your program, after a few lines I get to the statement

```
cin >> grade;
```

So then I read a number from the input and set `grade` to that number.

Then I enter the `while` loop. Notice that I never go back to any line earlier than the `while` loop. And there is no other line of the program that takes any input from `cin`. So I never read anything from `cin` again.

You can type all the numbers you want after the first one. The program isn't reading any of them. It's busy doing what you told it to do, which is to keep looping while 
`grade` is not equal to -1.
It will continue looping until something else happens to stop the program from running,
because `grade` is never getting changed within the loop.
Every time you come to the top of the loop, `grade` is still equal to the first number you entered.

By the way, the `if` with the `break` at the end of the loop is completely redundant.
If you did not have that `if`, the program would next go back to the top of the loop and then if `grade` were equal to -1 it would exit. So either way you exit at the end of the loop if `grade` becomes -1 during the loop.

Comment: I hear talking to a "Rubber Duck" helps too -- [**How to debug small programs**](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) (worth keeping the link handy for such questions `:)`

Answer (score 1):

*Side note:* With `while(grade != -1)`, the `if (grade != -1) break;` is redundant/superflous.

But, when you try to square a number, you are using `pow(2,x)` which is "2 raised to the x power"--Not what you want.

To square a number `x`, you want: `pow(x,2)`

Comment: Or even simpler and more efficient `x * x` `:)`

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin There's one in every crowd, David :-)

Comment: And the bigger the crowd, the more of them there are in there `:)`